# Should i disconnect after using a ssh through php?

Tags: laravel, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

If i use chmod to a folder inside a sftp server just like this:

```
    public function connection()
    {  
  //connection  
        $ssh = new SSH2('10.10.10.10');
        if (!$ssh->login('login', 'passwrd')) 
        {
          exit('Login Failed');
        }
  //chmod command
        echo $ssh->exec('sudo chmod -R 775 test_folder');
     }
```

after using the chmod command, should i disconnect doing something like this:

```
$ssh->disconnect();
```

or it's ok to keep that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you're done with your SSH commands, you should `disconnect` as a good practice

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessary. The destructor calls `disconnect` when the object is destroyed..

Comment: Well, thats a nice information, thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, do you mind to share some resource about the destructor and its attempt to call disconnect when the object is destroyed. Is the destructor called if an Exception is thrown?

Comment: @Bahman.A - that would be my expectation. If the exception isn't caught the program will terminate and I would expect all destructors to be called. And if it is caught...  when whether or not the destructor even ought to be called just depends. See https://3v4l.org/4tNvZ for example. An exception being thrown / caught does not automatically mean that the destructor should be called.